# R Conditional replacement of NAs based on text in another column

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

New to R, this has me stumped.

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this.

```
SPECIES   REST.TYPE
O         NA
O         Long
NR        NA
O         Short
NR        NA
O         NA
```

I want to replace the `NA`'s in `REST.TYPE` with `Present`, but only when `SPECIES = O` and replace the `NA`'s in `REST.TYPE` with `NR` when `SPECIES=NR`.

Required output

```
SPECIES   REST.TYPE
O         Present
O         Long
NR        NR
O         Short
NR        NR
O         Present
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Based on the "SPECIES" value of "O" and the NA elements in "REST.TYPE", we assign the "REST.TYPE" to "Present".  Then, we assign (`:=`) the 'REST.TYPE' to 'SPECIES' based on the remaining NA values in 'REST.TYPE'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[is.na(REST.TYPE) & SPECIES=="O", REST.TYPE := "Present"]
df1[is.na(REST.TYPE), REST.TYPE := SPECIES]
df1
#   SPECIES REST.TYPE
#1:       O   Present
#2:       O      Long
#3:      NR        NR
#4:       O     Short
#5:      NR        NR
#6:       O   Present
```

---

We can also do this with `base R` using `ifelse`

```
with(df1, ifelse(SPECIES=="O" & is.na(REST.TYPE), "Present", 
          ifelse(is.na(REST.TYPE), SPECIES, REST.TYPE)))
#[1] "Present" "Long"    "NR"      "Short"   "NR"      "Present"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SPECIES = c("O", "O", "NR", "O", "NR", "O"), 
REST.TYPE = c(NA, 
"Long", NA, "Short", NA, NA)), .Names = c("SPECIES", "REST.TYPE"  
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```